# How to make an unique id for an object that is not random

Tags: java, unique-id

### Problem

I need to create a unique `id` for each `Person` object.

```
public interface Person 
{
    String getName();
}

public class Chef implements Person
{
    String name;
    ....
    // all other instance variables are not unique to this object.
}
public class Waiter implements Person
{
    String name;
    ....
    // all other instance variables are not unique to this object.
}
```

---

### Extra information

All other instance variables inside the `Chef` are not unique to a particular `Chef`. Nor can we add any extra variables inside the `Chef` class to make it unique. This is because this information is coming from a back-end server and I cannot modify the `Chef` class. **This is a distributed system.**

### What I am trying to do

I want to create an integer that lets me map this `Person` object. I have tried to create a "unique" `id`.

```
private int makeId(Person person)
{
    int id = person.getName()
        .concat(person.getClass().getSimpleName())
        .hashCode();

    return id;
}
```

However, I know that this is not really unique because hashCode for a name is not guaranteeing anything uniqueness.

Without using random can I make this `id` unique?

*I apologize for the misunderstanding*, but I cannot add more fields to my `Chef` or `Waiter` object class and the **application is distributed**.

Comment: More unique than what? You can't make it more unique then what you put into the id-making process - and in your case, that's the person's name - so two people with the same name would always result in the same id, no matter how you tweak the process (if you want it to be reproducible for the same input; otherwise you're getting into randomness)

Comment: May be, you just need UUID?

Comment: This might be a x/y problem. What would you actually need the id for? You can't generate a unique id generated from one field and without using some kind of randomness. Can you give more context here?

Comment: @ModusTollens I need to make each `Person` unique. That is even though they may have the same name I need them to be stored differently in a hashmap. Again this is a distributed application so the answer by @Malt doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Add the requirement to your question please. What are key and value objects of the HashMap?

Comment: @ModusTollens Thanks, I added as many requirements as possible. Is it more clear now?

Comment: @J_Strauton Please add a more detailed description of your distributed system to your question. Also add a description on how you want to use this ID in your distributed system. Does this ID have to be an integer or can it be something else like a String or UUID? Is it a requirement that the calculation/generation of the ID depends on the fields of the `Person` object or can it be generated/assigned independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding a globally unique identifier (GUID)?

A GUID is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes) that can be used across all computers and networks wherever a unique identifier is required. Such an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated.

In Java, it is called a [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html). For example:

```
UUID uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID();

System.out.println(uuid.toString());
```

Answer (score 10):

If your application isn't distributed, just use a static counter during construction:

```
public class Chef {

    private static int nextId = 1;

    private final String name;
    private final int id;

    public Chef(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = Chef.nextId++;
    }
}
```

The id of the first `Chef` will be 1, the second will be 2 etc.

If your program is multi threaded, use an `AtomicInteger` for `nextId` instead of a plain `int`.

Just don't use `hashCode` as a unique id. Hash codes **by definition** don't have to be unique.

Comment: That is not my problem. Adding a new id is not part of my problem. And my application is distributed.

Comment: Then I suggest you rephrase the question and add all relevant information

Comment: If you modify the problem to provide an answer is that really answering the question?